# Why squidguard tell me default acl is missing but it isn't?

Tags: debian, proxy, squid

I have a problem with squidguard when i want to create .db files.

When i do :

`squidGuard -c "/etc/squid3/squidGuard.conf" -C all -d`

It tell me :

```
squidGuard: FATAL; default acl not defined in file /etc/squid3/squidGuard.conf
```

But in my squidGuard.conf, it is defined ..

[image]

Thanks for your help

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe you forgotten that in your squidGuard.conf:

```
src clients {
    ip 10.10.101.0/24 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clients was defined, i've downloaded source of squidGuard and compiled them. Fixed !